# Definition of Fermi level

Tags: semiconductor-physics, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

In [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level), there is following sentence.

> The Fermi level of a solid-state body is the thermodynamic work required to add one electron to the body. It is a thermodynamic quantity usually denoted by µ or $E_F$.

But I'm not sure what "body" and "electron" mean here.

What means body in here?
And, What kind of electron is this article talking about?

Answer (score 0):

A rigid body with a fixed lattice of positive point charges.

For simplicity. its a cube with opposite faces idientified, a flat 3-torus.

At temperature zero, the electron gas, by lattice 3-periodicity, has a threefold system eigenstates of plane waves.

The system may be labled by a dicrete set of wave vectors, that can be reduced by Blochs theorem to harmonic waves $e^{i \vec k \cdot \vec x}$ times a lattice periodic function $u_{k,b}(x)$, where b is a band index for nearly continuous intervals of the energy spectrum, that typicall are split by the interaction from highly degenerate states in the interaction free case.

By the Pauli principle, these states are filled, on electron for each state according to the energy order, until the system is electrically neutral.

The ground state is:

All states below the Fermi level $\hbar \omega(k) = E_f$ full, all above emtpy.

Typically, the Fermi level is equivalent to a thermic energy $\text{k T} = 10 \ \text{e V}$, yielding a temperature equivalent of such a free kinetic energy of about $10000\ \text{ K}$.

Since the Fermi level is so very high above the thermic Boltzmann level, only a very thin layer at the band surface is involved in thermodynamic storage processes, but, by their high kinetic energy, the more so in transport processes as conduction,  electrically and thermically.

In the case, that the highest band is full and the energy gap to the next band is - by a small number of kT energy packets - big, the electron system does not take part in thermodynamics at all, its an insulator. In such e system, the Fermi level in in the mid between to band edges.

In  typical metallic conductors, the Fermi level is in the middle  of the band and any number of electrons at the band edge behave like a free electon gas of exited electons and their positive charged holes, they leave below the Fermi level.

In this case the chemical potential $\mu$, is the energy, nessessary to lift a single electron from 0 to $E_f+..$, so that it can enter the system from an external 1-particle reservoir in a state with energy 0, eg an electron of an H-Atom in a highly excited bound state.

Comment: Since the Fermi energy is a thermodynamic quantity, it applies to any solid (or liquid) phase, regardless of atomic positions.

Comment: While hard to construct the electron energy levels of a non-symmetric (non-crystalline) system, that does not mean that a Fermi energy does not exist. And the Fermi energy certainly is relevant in systems such as amorphous semiconductors.

Comment: Are you trying to argue that the Gibbs free energy (from which the Fermi energy derives) only applies to crystalline systems?